# Помощь в составлении функции округления в массиве

Tags: python, массивы, округление

хотелось бы узнать возможный способ округления элементов массива, сумма элементов которого в конечном счете будет равна длине массива.

```
def minimass():
    i,f,g=0,0,sum(rel)
    while i<len(rel):
        rel[i]=round(rel[i]/(g/len(rel)))
        i+=1
    print(rel)
    return rel


rel=[40,21,16.5,22.5]
print(len(rel))
minimass()

В ответе данного примера получается [2, 1, 1, 1] и сумма всех элементов не равна длине, я же хочу получить сумму равную длинне
Правильное решение [1,1,1,1] должно получиться по следующей схеме

40-25=15 
21-25=-4 
16.5-25=-8.5 
22.5-25=-2.5

25/2=12.5

15-12.5=2.5 [1] Требуется округлить по условию! Это значение точно округлится 100%
-4+12.5=8.5 [1]
-8.5+12.5=4 [1]
-2.5+12.5=10 [1] это значение не округлится 100%
```

Comment: бррр, а можно поподробнее, а то из описания не очень ясно в чем суть задачи, что за округления

Comment: Хотелось бы функцию, чтобы число максимальное близкое к округлению принимало соответствующее значение, но сумма элементов массива не превосходило его длинны. Что-то на подобии линейной регрессии

Comment: а можно какой-нибудь маленький пример с пояснениями

Comment: [54,23,23] сумма этого ряда чисел делится на 3. У нулевого элемента от деления разность составляет +21, у второго и третьего -10. Задача в том, чтобы функция определяла элемент с наименьшей разностью (не важно + или -) и округляла его в соответствующую сторону, но чтобы сумма элементов массива в свою очередь была строго равна длине массива. Приблизительный результат данного примера должен получиться [2,1,0] или [2,0,1]

Comment: 54+23+23 = 100 (сумма ряда) - на 3 не делится, `от деления разность составляет` - а что такое разность от деления и от деления на что именно в данном случае?

Comment: Делится, но получается остаток 33.333... имею ввиду ±от каждого элемента. Наименьший ± от элемента округляется в меньшую сторону, или же наоборот, если элементов недостаточно до его длинны при стандартном округлении (round), в большую, чтобы соответствовало условию сумма конечных элементов строго равно колву элементов с списке

Answer (score 0):

По мере округления ошибка переносится на следующие элементы. В итоге это приведёт к тому что сумма округлённого массива будет равна сумме исходного.

Подгонка суммы массива вынесена в отдельную функцию:

```
def norm_arr(a):
    s = sum(rel)
    return [len(rel) * v / s for v in rel]


def round_arr(a):
    b = []
    error = 0
    for v in a:
        r = round(v + error)
        b.append(r)
        error = v - r
    return b


rel = [40, 21, 16.5, 22.5]
print(round_arr(norm_arr(rel)))
```

> ```
> $ python round_arr.py
> [2, 0, 2, 0]
> ```

**P.S.** Это традиционный способ снижения битности изображений - пикселы округляются, а сумма (яркость картинки) остаётся примерно такой же. В вашем случае задачу можно ставить по разному, этот способ может подойти.

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к выводу, что это скорее всего правильная реализация:

```
def minimass():
    i,f,g,boc,ab,gb,res_gb=0,0,sum(rel),[],0,[],[]
    while i<len(rel):
        rel[i]=(rel[i]/(g/len(rel)))
        i+=1
    i=0
    while i<len(rel):
        boc.append(round(rel[i]))
        i+=1
    if sum(rel)!=sum(boc):
        if sum(rel)<sum(boc):
            ab=sum(boc)-sum(rel)
            i=0
            while i<len(rel):
                gb.append(rel[i]%1)
                i+=1
            res_gb=sorted(gb)
            print(gb)
            print(res_gb)
            i=0
            while i<ab:
                boc[gb.index(res_gb[i])]=boc[gb.index(res_gb[i])]-1
                i+=1
            print(boc)
        else:
            ab=sum(rel)-sum(boc)
            i=0
            while i<len(rel):
                gb.append(rel[i]%1)
                i+=1
            res_gb=sorted(gb)
            print(gb)
            print(res_gb)
            i=0
            while i<ab:
                boc[gb.index(res_gb[i])]=boc[gb.index(res_gb[i])]+1
                i+=1
            print(boc)
```